# Which character(s) can I safely use to express custom meaning in regular expression

Tags: regex, windows, language-agnostic, filesystems

Users in my application will use the regex to specify which file(s) the application should take and which it should exclude, e.g. include files matching `foo.*\.txt`

However sometimes the filter will need to use value that can only be known by the application at runtime. For example, if the filter is `foo[SPECIALVALUEHERE].*\.txt` and the special value happens to be bar, the actual filter will be `foobar.*\.txt`

Which characters can be used for specifying the [SPECIALVALUEHERE]? I guess to avoid ambiguity, it would need to be not a special/reserved character in regex, and not a character that would occur in a file. Another requirement from the customer is that it must be one (or at most two or three) characters only, so stuff like %SPECIALVALUE% is out of the question.

Any suggestion which character or character combination can I use for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows you can use for example `=` which is not a special character in regex but is not allowed in filenames ([here a table of characters that can't be used in windows filenames](http://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/web/resources/cms/characters-to-avoid.html)). You can then replace the = with what you need.

Otherwise on unix systems it is quite a mess as any byte sequence can be part of the filename without restrictions, [here a reference question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/150740/linux-windows-unix-file-names-which-characters-are-allowed-which-are-unesc), so, even if language agnostic, you should at least decide on which systems you are going to use the regex.

Comment: Then you can use `=` :) it is not a regex character (it's ok using it in the regex) *and* it is not allowed in filenames, thus you won't find it in any filename (if this is what you were asking for, I'm starting to doubt)

Comment: You are correct, this is what I am looking for. Thanks. Do you know if there is any other character(s)?

Comment: I linked a page (*here a table of characters...*) that should show you a list of characters not allowed in filenames. You can use those characters if they aren't in the list of special characters provided by @raina77ow. However, if you need to use multiple special values and if those values are not attached one another you can just use `=` for the first and `==` for the second. Just remember to replace `==` before `=`, otherwise your `==` will be replaced as two single `=`

Answer (score 1):

There's only 12 symbols that have special meaning in regexes (outside of character class) and should be escaped:

- unicharacter: `.`
- string start/end anchors: `^ $`
- quantifiers: `+ * ?`
- capturing group delimiters: `( )`
- quantifier opening delimiter: `{`
- character class opening delimiter: `[`
- alternation symbol: `|`
- and, the last, escaping symbol itself: `\`

To escape them (=strip of special meaning) just prepend them with `\` symbol. To delimit a special part of regex, you can use any non-special and non-alphanumeric symbol: `#` and `~` come to mind immediately. )

As a sidenote, in Perl you can automatically quote a part of regex with `\Q...\E` operators.

Comment: Hmm, I have the feeling this is the right answer for completely another question?

Answer (score 1):

I have used double curly brackets for this sort of thing.  None of the regex dialects I use recognize curlies inside curlies for anything, and so it is not a valid string in a regex.  `foo{{SPECIALVALUEHERE}}\.txt`